# Regex - how to remove 8 digits onwards with regex

Tags: regex

I want to get only the numbers from a string to a maximum length of 7 characters using RegEx.

This is what I tried so far:[`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/fjbdtvkb/)

Example:

`Samsung Galaxy Edge  $1.234.000 text text text 23 text  1289`

The RegEx should output:

`1234000`

Comment: in which language  u using . what is the exact need u  want from the result.

Comment: What happens in your example if it's a "Samsung Galaxy Edge 2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one :

```
$("td").each(function() {
  $(this).html(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').slice(0,7);
  });
});
```

**[demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjbdtvkb/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

`perl -p -e 's/\D+//g' test | perl -p -e '/(\d{7})/ ; print "$1\n"'`
% 1234000

**Edit - some explanations**
The first part of the expression removes everything which isn't a number (`test` is a file containing your line) *I try to delete all the characters, except numbers*, the second part looks for the first 7 digits in the result of the first part and prints them to the screen *and then delete the number 7 onwards*.
I don't know what language you're using, but the regexp essentials should be the same.